# Tooltip Mouse-Overflow in Magento

Tags: magento

how i can add a tooltip mouseoverflow button in magento.

E.g.

Tshirt-Color [tooltip mouseoverflow button]:
red
green
black

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery ui tooltip: http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use tooltip using css check below code may be help you

```
<style>
.tooltip{display: inline;position: relative;}
.tooltip:hover:after{background: #333;background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);border-radius: 5px;bottom: 10px;color: #fff;content: attr(title);
            left: 20%;padding: 5px 15px;position: absolute;z-index: 98;width: 220px;}
.tooltip:hover:before{border: solid;border-color: #333 transparent;border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;bottom: 6px;content: "";left: 50%;position: absolute;z-index: 99;}
.tip{display:inline-block;padding-left:12px;}
</style>
<div class="tip">
  <a href="#" title="Enter Value here" class="tooltip">mouse hover here</a></div>
```